# tig に untracked なファイルが表示されない

Tags: git

tig の status view に untracked なファイルが全く表示されなくなり、原因がわからず困っています。

なお、`git status` では untracked なファイルも表示されていて、`git add` することができます（つまり .gitignore の問題ではないと考えています）。
`git add` してみると untracked だったファイルが `status view` の `changes to be committed` 欄に表示されるようになりますが、<kbd>u</kbd>を押すと `untracked files` の欄に移動せず消えてしまいます。

何が原因でしょうか。あるいは、このような振る舞いに変更されたのでしょうか。

tig の version は 2.0.3 で、.tigrc は以下の通りです。表示を制御するような設定は記述していません。

```
# Bind
bind generic g move-first-line
bind generic G move-last-line
bind generic <Ctrl-f> move-page-down
bind generic <Ctrl-b> move-page-up
bind status C !git commit -v
```

よろしくお願いします。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

同じような問題が issue として上がっていますね。

[tig status does not show untracked files outside of current directory · Issue #230](https://github.com/jonas/tig/issues/230)

私の環境(tig 1.2.1, git 1.9.1)でもカレントディレクトリよりも上位ディレクトリにある untrack ファイルは表示されません。根本的な解決ではありませんが、常にリポジトリのトップディレクトリで tig を実行すれば良いのではないでしょうか。

追加:

tig のソースコードを少しみてみましたが、`tig.c` に以下の様なコードがあり、

```
static const char *status_list_other_argv[] = {
    "git", "ls-files", "-z", "--others", "--exclude-standard", opt_prefix, NULL, NULL,
};
```

`git ls-files --others ...` で untracked ファイルを抽出しています。カレントディレクトリよりも上位のディレクトリにある untracked ファイルが表示されないのはこれが原因の様です。git の他のサブコマンドで置き換えられると良いのですが、untracked ファイルだけを表示するというものが思い浮かびません(`git ls-tree --full-tree --name-only HEAD` や `git status -s` などの出力結果を加工すれば良いのでしょうが…)。

シェルの関数として、

```
tig() { (cd $(git rev-parse --show-toplevel) && command tig "$@") }
```

などと定義しておけば良いのかもしれません。

Comment: ありがとうございます。
実はあの後、原因不明に再現しなくなりました。

できるだけ条件は同じにしていたのですが、カレントディレクトリが意図しているところとは別のディレクトリだったのかもしれません。heliac2001さんの回答の可能性が高いため、accepted に選びました。